# China tag has to go

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

[china](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china) seems to be the only country tag. [china-firewall](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-firewall) would be more useful, but it seems that only one of the three question is referring to it. Such a categorization is just not useful.

Can we retag it to remove it completely? Objections?

Comment: I merged it with [tag:international], seemed the most apropos. I didn't make it a permanent synonym though, I see no reason to keep to keep it hanging around - if you see it pop up again, just retag it. (If it becomes a recurring problem we can reconsider, but I doubt it will come to that).

Comment: APT has/had for some time been synonymous with China. Depending on the question, APT could also be used.